# Android bluetooth read

Tags: android, loops, bluetooth, try-catch, read-write

Using this article as a guide:

[Managing a Connection](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection)

It explains that in the connected thread class, the run method is constantly listening for data to read from the stream.

So if I put a log message in the loop I'd expect to see a constant feed of my message when the instance of this class is created and I `start()` it, however I only get the message once. If i remove the try catch block of code though then I do see a constant feed of my logcat message. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: No one has any input? I'm leaning towards improper catching? If the exception encountered isn't the one expected in catch then the program wont loop right? However how am I to know what other expections this might throw? Would adding a 'finally' part at the end fix all my problems? Or is that not the correct way to do it?

Comment: UPDATE: Even 
finally {
continue;
}
doesnt work... :/